# how to resize the popup dropdown dialog in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, spinner

I am trying to create a multiselect spinner with checkbox, but I dont know how to that so I came up on doing an altenative dropdown multiselect popupdialog. I was able to show the the pop up window but my problem is.. as you can see in the picture, the pop up window do not align on the information type box... Can you help me on that?

[image: The picture show the a button and a popupwindow as a dropdown dialog in my project]

here is my code in popupInformationType.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/PopUpViewInformationType"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+DropDownList/dropDownListInfoType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/cachecolorhint"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code on my dro_down_list_infotype.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+DropDownList/checkboxInfoType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+DropDownList/SelectOptionInfoType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is a part of my code in MainActivity that calls the popup window

```
private void initiatePopUpInfoType(ArrayList<String> informationTypes, TextView tv_InformationType){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)IreportMain.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //get the pop-up window i.e.  drop-down layout
    LinearLayout layoutInfoType = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_informationtype, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.PopUpViewInformationType));

    //get the view to which drop-down layout is to be anchored
    RelativeLayout layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
    pwInfoType = new PopupWindow(layoutInfoType, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);


    pwInfoType.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    pwInfoType.setTouchable(true);

    //let pop-up be informed about touch events outside its window. This  should be done before setting the content of pop-up
    pwInfoType.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    pwInfoType.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //dismiss the pop-up i.e. drop-down when touched anywhere outside the pop-up
    pwInfoType.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                pwInfoType.dismiss();
                return true;                    
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    //provide the source layout for drop-down
    pwInfoType.setContentView(layoutInfoType);

    //anchor the drop-down to bottom-left corner of 'layout2'
    pwInfoType.showAsDropDown(layout2);

    //populate the drop-down list
    final ListView listInfoType = (ListView) layoutInfoType.findViewById(R.DropDownList.dropDownListInfoType);
    InfoTypeListAdapter adapter = new InfoTypeListAdapter(this, informationTypes, tv_InformationType);
    listInfoType.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: u can also try with pwInfoType.setWidth(tv_InformationType.getWidth());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solve it. I just put the two listview in one xml file then it create two columns. Here is my code in xml.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/PopUpView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ListView
    android:id="@+DropDownList/dropDownListBrand"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/cachecolorhint"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp">
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+DropDownList/dropDownListInfoType"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/cachecolorhint"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
</ListView>
```

Comment: You can accept you own answer, so is easier for other people with the same problem to see that this answer has an accepted question.